# How to activate the SharePoint portal on an existing project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, tfs

I created a TFS project, but when we created the project we didn't created any SharePoint portal with it.

But now we have some needs which can justify it. I cannot find how to activate it?

If I try to go on the project, I got Unauthorized error(and I'm project admin).

Edit: On Project portal Settings, Project Portal. The project portal is enabled. So what are needed rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this page will address what you are after: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462861.aspx.

Comment: You can see this videos, they will describe in details what you will need to do and how also to test that everything are working well http://tfs10enterprise.codeplex.com/releases/view/78529#DownloadId=313135